# How to remove images from MEDIA_ROOT by using "Clear" in Admin panel for ImageField in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I am trying to find the way to remove images from MEDIA_ROOT when I'am using "Clear" in Admin panel.

[Image that shows the checkbox I want to use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKJaS.jpg)

When I choice "Clear" option, it removes link to image from database but the image is still in MEDIA_ROOT.

It there a way to change its behavior?

I tried to look Django documentation and googling but I didn't find anything.

Comment: This is not very straight forward to do. But my suggestion will be use Django's signal `pre_save ` and `post_delete`. The `pre_save` signal checks if the image field is cleared (set to None) and deletes the file if it exists. The `post_delete` signal ensures that the file is also removed when the entire record is deleted.

Comment: @MohammadGolamDostogir Thank's for idea, I have never used Django's signals before. I will learn about it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.